# Proving that a function sequence converges uniformly to limit function

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I have the function sequence $f_n = n\sinh(x/n)$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall x \in [-1, 1]$ which I believe has the limit function $f = 1$ for $x = 1, f = 0$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $f = -1$ for $x = -1$.

How would I go about proving that $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly? I know that $f_n \rightarrow f$ iff $f_n \rightarrow f$ in the uniform topology. So I should somehow be able to use the metric that induces the uniform topology to prove that $f_n$ converges uniformly. Is it enough to show that the derivatives of the functions are bounded by some value not dependent on $x$?

Comment: The limit function you claim is discontinuous.

Comment: Actually, $f(x)=x$ for all $x$. How did you compute the point-wise limit?

Comment: It does converge uniformly, but the identity function x->x

Answer (score -1):

$e^{t}=1+t+tg(t)$ where $g(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$ (and $g$ is continuous on $[0,1]$). [ To see this either use Taylor expansion to apply L'Hopital's Rule to $\frac {e^{t+-1-t}} t$].

Hence $n\frac {e^{x/n}-e^{-x/n}} 2 =x+\frac  x n [g(x/n)-g(-x/n)]$.

Note that $g(t)=\frac {e^{t}-1-t} t$ and $g(0)=0$ defines a continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $e^{t}=1+t+tg(t)$ for all $t$. Being a continuous function $g$ is bounded Suppose $|g(t)| \leq M$ for all $t$. Then $|\frac  x n [g(x/n)-g(-x/n)]| \leq 2M \frac 1 n$ for all $x$. Hence $\sup_x  |\frac  x n [g(x/n)-g(-x/n)]|  \to 0$ proving uniform convergence.

Comment: I see why this method gives us the pointwise convergence, as $x+x/n [g(x/n - g(-x/n)) \rightarrow x, n \rightarrow \infty$. However I do not see how we can use it to find uniform convergence. I think we should apply Weierstrass' Majorant test, however I'm not sure what to choose as the majorant due to the x. By taking the absolute value we end up with $x(1+1/ncosh(x/n))$

Comment: Ah, if we do $x+x/n[g(x/n)-g(-x/n) - x$, we end up with a limit that is 0 as n goes to infinity, so it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @StannisBa I have added a detailed proof.